# How I have to load tinymce into ID-element a few times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

When I try to load tinymce editor without any div-blocks it works good even when I launch my fucntion a few times by a click. When I add editor into div-block it works only one time. What I have to change to force editor to work right?

I add 2 global variables in javascript which I generate from PHP.
These two variables are written in one line, for comfort I wrote them in column. Unfortunately this code doesn't work here cause it cannot load library tiny.

> JS

```
<script>
var a = "<textarea id='comments'></textarea><script>
tinymce.init({
selector: 'textarea#comments', 
language : 'en',
width : '100%',
height : 220, 
plugins: ['link image paste dlebutton'],
theme: 'modern',
relative_urls : false,
convert_urls : false,
remove_script_host : false,
extended_valid_elements : 'div[align|class|style|id|title]',
paste_as_text: true, 
toolbar_items_size: 'small',
statusbar : false });<\/script>";

var b = "<div id='subload'></div>";
</script>
```

> Html code

```
<div id="click">Click</div>
<div id="load"></div>
```

> Jq

```
    $('#click').click(function() {  
    $('#load').html(b);
    $('#subload').html(a); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, okay, I've found an answer. I can just reload tiny like this:

```
tinymce.remove();
tinymce.init({selector: 'textarea'});
```